# Can I get the Current Working Directory in SystemTap under RHEL6

Tags: rhel6, systemtap, working-directory

I have the following SystemTap program:

```
#!/usr/bin/stap
function proc:string() {
    return sprintf("[%s] %s(%s)::%s() (pid %d, uid %d, cwd %s)",
        execname(), cmdline_arg(0), cmdline_args(1,-1,", "), caller(), pid(), uid(),
        fullpath_struct_path(task_cwd_path(task_current()))
    );
}

probe syscall.open.return, syscall.stat.return,
    syscall.open64.return ?, syscall.stat64.return ? {
    filename = user_string($filename);
    if ($return < 0) {
        eno = -$return;
        printf("%s => %s '%s' by %s\n", pn(), errno_str(eno), filename, proc());
    }
}
```

when run it gets the following error:

> semantic error: unresolved function (similar: d_path, inode_path, task_cpu, task_current, task_dentry_path): identifier 'task_cwd_path' at /tmp/stap-test:5:30

which I believe is because Red Hat did not add the `task_cwd_path()` function until RHEL7.  Is there an alternative way to return the current directory that will work with RHEL6?